# Conservation of angular momentum, pion-deuteron reaction

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, pions

If I have the following reaction : $\pi^- + d \rightarrow n + n$, it's said that the two neutrons are in a state with s=1 and l=1, so that $j_f =l+s$$\space \rightarrow$ $j_f =0,1,2$ . And that the spins of the **pion** and **deuteron** should be 0 and 1 respectively, while their relative orbital angular momentum ($l_i$) is 0. That means $j_i =1$, but if $j_f = 2$ doesn't that violate the conservation of angular momentum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means that you can't have $j_f=2$. This is the reaction from which the parity of the pion was first deduced by the way!